# Android WebView Background Color Problem

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a **webview** in which I am showing some html text, for the same webview I have put **background color**  as **white** both in xml and in the Java class. My problem is that if the text is short, only the part of the screen which has text appears with background color as white and after that the rest of the webview appears with **black background** color. Please help.

Comment: can you post your xml code please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you  changed the layout height and weight to fill parent ?
Also is the webview child of some other layout? It's properties also affect the layout parameters of the web view.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using RGB instead of ARGB. Zero alpha.